# Google Charts - I want the axis to not show every item

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm not sure how to describe this, so I've taken a series of screenshots of my Google Chart:

1. How it looks full screen
2. How it looks half screen
3. How it looks about quarter screen

As you can see, resizing the browser window makes the chart shrink (which is fine). But it causes the axis data to also change. I like how it is in 1 and 3, but not 2.

I want to make it *never* put axis data on 2 lines. I'd be happy if in number 2 it just started skipping numbers like it does in number 3.

[image]

How can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a resize event:

```
window.onresize = $scope.drawChart;
```

Inside `drawChart` I have:

```
options.hAxis.showTextEvery = (window.innerWidth < 1700) ? 7 : 1;
```

So when the window width hits a certain point, the chart axis labels revert from daily to weekly.

Hope that helps someone.